# Check for img vote by IP address

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, joomla1.7

So I have a Joomla 1.7 website and I am using JoomGallery Version 2.0.0 BETA5 to display images and allow users to vote on them. The component already captures userip, picid and vote (see image below). So I need to know what I can put in my joomGallery template to show a "RATED!" indicator by the picture.

Here's what the table looks like in phpMyAdmin:
[table http://ican.stealthstl.com/table.png](http://ican.stealthstl.com/table.png)

I know it needs to be like IF current_userip = table_userip and current_picid = table_picid
and those two exist in the same table entry then display "RATED!" Actually I'll be displaying text and an image of a check mark.

Here's what I want it to look like:
[table http://ican.stealthstl.com/gallery.png](http://ican.stealthstl.com/gallery.png)

Let me know if you need any more information. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: what are you asking? you say ip address, dont ask anything about an ip address, then show a picture of what you want it to look like.  Where is the coding problem? This doesnt seem like a proper question for SO from what i am reading...

Comment: This just feels like a time where the OP needs to give it a try first or hire a freelancer

Comment: I need to know how to write the if statement I mentioned. and capture the data for it that I need. So my question is: How do I say if a user has already voted on this image show "something"?

Comment: it uses the USERID to determine if a user already voted on the pics.. are you allowing users who arent signed in to vote? why would you want to use an IP address otherwise?

Comment: yes, it has a function built in to track registered user's votes. However, I don't want to require everyone who wants to vote to register.

Comment: That's not going to work reliably as the IP can change. Anyways, could you please show us some code, and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Now that i understand the question, you can still use USERID to place into the table, since using IP address is easy to bypass, and if a user is in a heavily populated IP address area such as a university campus, only one user will be counted (for whatever time interval you want to prevent votes from)

you determine the ip address of the person voting through:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

now check if the ip address has already been added (where a USERID isnt being used [if they havent signed in])

```
$query="SELECT count(*) as total WHERE userid="null" and ip='$ip'"; //count of already added
$executequery = $conn->Execute($query);
$iptotal = $executequery->fields['total']; //total of the count
```

if that ip isn't yet used, put it into the database

```
if($iptotal<1) //not yet added? 
{
    INSERT INTO votetable SET ip='$ip', vote='$voterating' WHERE picid=$picid //insert new vote
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I think it definitely points me in the right direction. I just wasn't sure how to approach this. I can use this to get the info I need and display my "RATED!" sign.

Comment: No problem, just keep in mind that IP addresses can prevent a large amount of votes in heavy connection areas.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good thought. I'm sure I would have hated myself later if I worked through all this around the IP and realized my mistake afterwards.